# Android Studio Project structure issue

Tags: java, android-studio, pepper

I am currently doing my master thesis, and i have to code Pepper the humanoid by SoftBank. I decided i wanted to use Android studio, but i am pretty new to this. The issue im having a hard time with is Resolved JDK_1_8, i tried to uninstall and install JDK 15 so many times, and reinstalling android studio too. enter image description here.

I think it might have to do something with JDK Location which is

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: What is it exactly that does not work? Please explain precise steps of reproduction, and report the output directly.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the JDK, the next step is to add it to the system variables and you will be fine.
[Edit Environment Path in Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yngRy.jpg)

Comment: Hi @Compsineer - your answer is for Windows 10.  The OP is doing on OSX - are you sure this is really going to help?